# What kind of sources support ol.source.ImageVector in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm trying to draw vector tiles in OpenLayers 3, and I want to test the performance of image vectors, as the volume i have is too much for the browser to handle.

This is the docs on ImageVector class

> **ol.source.ImageVector**
>
> An image source whose images are canvas elements into which vector
> features read from a vector source (ol.source.Vector) are drawn. An
> ol.source.ImageVector object is to be used as the source of an image
> layer (ol.layer.Image).

according to that, all the sources of the type ol.source.Vector should work. The three for that class is the following:

```
ol.source.Vector 
 |_ ol.source.Cluster
 |_ ol.source.FormatVector
    |__ ol.source.ServerVector
    |__ ol.source.StaticVector
    |   |__ ol.source.GeoJSON
    |   |__ ol.source.GPX
    |   |__ ol.source.IGC
    |   |__ ol.source.KML
    |   |__ ol.source.OSMXML
    |   |__ ol.source.TopoJSON
    |__ ol.source.TileVector
```

So, for what I understand, I should be able to use any of those sources for the ImageVector source. So, I'm trying something like the following, with no success.

```
    var waterVectorSource = new ol.source.TileVector({
        format: new ol.format.TopoJSON(),
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
        tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.XYZ({
            maxZoom: 19
        }),
        url: 'http://{a-c}.tile.openstreetmap.us/' +
            'vectiles-water-areas/{z}/{x}/{y}.topojson'
    })

    var imageVectorSource = new ol.source.ImageVector({
        source:waterVectorSource
    });

    var imageLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
        source:imageVectorSource
    });
    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
            /*new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})}),*/
            imageLayer 
        ],
        view: new ol.View({                
            zoom: 13
        })
    });
```

Tried the same thing with a ServerVector instead of TileVector, but they don't work. No function execution (the former) or web call (the latter) is made.  The only examples I have seen of the ImageVector class ([like this one](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/image-vector-layer.html)) use children of the StaticVector class.

Do anyone have an idea of what kind of datasources can you use for an ImageVector class?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After getting in touch with the developers, I ended with a solution for this. Turns out there's a bug with the ImageVector class that prevents it to call the loadFeatures function. They fixed in a developer version and PR was created.

See [this thread in Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ol3-dev/sScaKKx2744) for more details